# Creating a new transaction for every request in a JMeter ForLoop

Tags: jmeter

I have two steps that need to be in a separate transaction for each iteration of the loop. However what is happening is to show the sum of how long it took all requests to complete within the loop.

Example

```
- transaction
- /getRecomendations x1 <-- returns 5 id's

- /click x5 (transaction)
  - for-loop
   - post

- /views x5 (transaction)
  - for-loop
   - post
```

In the report the request show the same requests. So what is happening is

```
1x /getRecomendations 
1x /click 
1x /views
```

not

```
1x /getRecomendations 
5x /click 
5x /views
```

I have also tried

```
- transaction
- /getRecomendations x1 <-- returns 5 id's

- /click x5 (for-loop)
  - transaction
   - post

- /views x5 (for-loop)
  - transaction
   - post
```

However only the /getRecomendations renders in the report.

Advice?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which are being generated from the `/getRecomendations` request using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html).

[ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) works with JMeter Variables in form of:

```
var_1=foo
var_2=bar
var_3=baz
etc.
```

Given you set everything up properly ForEach Controller should generate a request per JMeter Variable with this numeric postfix.

[image]

If you see only 1 request instead of 5 most probably your [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) returns only one variable and you need to re-visit its configuration and amend it accordingly.

Comment: turns out it was the naming. The request was correct but once I name the transaction the same name of the request it worked.